# Automatically move On-Premise ML trained model to Azure storage

Tags: machine-learning, automation, azure-storage

When ML model gets trained, it should be moved automatically from on-premise to Azure storage.

How can I automate On-Premise ML trained model to be stored in Azure storage account, goal here is when the model gets trained it should automatically be stored inside a storage account containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions can help copying the trained model files from on-premise to Azure Storage.

1. To use [`azcopy sync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync) command to replicate the source location to the destination location. Evan if your on-premise OS is Linux, you can try to run it via `crontab` with an interval.
2. To use [`Azure/azure-storage-fuse`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse) to mount a container of Azure Blob Storage to Linux filesystem, then directly save the trained model files to the mounted path, if the on-premise trainning machine is Linux.
3. To use an Azure File Share with [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) or [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) or [macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-mac) via Samba 3.0 as a directory in your on-premise filesystem, then you can save the trained model files into it.
4. At the end of Python trainning script, to add some code using Azure Storage SDK for Python to directly upload the trained module files to Azure Storage.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can we automate this?
When the model gets trained it should automatically be stored inside a storage account containers.

Comment: @SarveshPandey Hi, I have given you 4 solutions. Now, I don't know what you mean about `automate this`, and your description is too simple and lack of the necessary details about what you want and what you did. Please update your post to improve that.

Comment: Hi Peter, the above 4 solutions is going to execute on one time. I want to repeat this step on daily/weekly basis. Can we repeat this automatically at scheduled time. Can we automate your solution?

Comment: @SarveshPandey Please carefully review my solutions. #1 Solution with a [`crontab`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm) command can automatically execute it daily or weekly as you wish. #2 and #3 solutions will directly write the files into Azure Storage without manually sync operating. #4 Solution is to write the code using Azure Storage SDK to sync files and add it behind your AI codes, then it will be executed to upload after you AI codes finished to save files on local.